# How to initiate a module in Rails only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to have a configuration module that is loaded only once.

My code is

```
module Configuration
  extend self

  def settings 
    @settings ||= # some code that loads the settings
  end
end

class SomeClass
  include Configuration

  def evaluate
    settings.get_some_setting
  end
end
```

I would expect the `@settings` to be evaluated and set once but when running a Rails server I see that `@settings` is recreated in different API calls to the server.

I assume that either I'm not using the variable correctly or the module is instantiated on every API call (probably due to different threads).

What would be the right way to have `@settings` evaluated only once?

Comment: Can you share some more code - where are you calling SomeClass#evaluate? Or you creating an instance of SomeClass every time?

Comment: what's `scope` of `settings` ? you want it's created only one time per class or for all classes ?

Comment: Also - are you talking about dev mode or production mode? In dev classes are being reloaded.

Comment: @JoelBlum - even if I set SomeClass to `extend self` I still get the `@settings` to be evaluated every time. I'm in Dev mode. Didn't think that the behavior might be different in Prod. Great point!

@Lam Phan - I would like the `@settings` to be created once for all classes

Comment: Rails reloads classes in dev mode so that changes in your code will get picked up on. It doesn't reload all of them though, it depends on your configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize once at boot time by including an initializer in config/initializers, for example:

```rb
# config/initializers/settings.rb

settings = # some code that generates the settings
config = Struct.new(:settings)
Configuration = config.new(settings)
```

then in your app, for example:

```rb
special_value = Configuration.settings.special_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct:

> the module is instantiated on every API call (probably due to different threads)

If the function is expensive, you can use Rails cache to memoize settings value:

```rb
def settings
  Rails.cache.fetch('settings') do
    init_settings
  end
end
```

Notice that `expires_in` param is omitted not to expire cache value.